# What are functions with the property $f(f(x)) = x$ called?

Tags: functions, terminology

Do functions which, when composed with themselves, are equivalent to the identity function (i.e. functions for which $f(f(x)) = x$ in general) have a name and if so, what is it?

Additionally, am I correct in saying that a such function has a splinter of two, or is it perhaps splinter of size 2 or something else entirely? Or could I say that a such function has an orbit of size 2?

Comment: [Involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution). I have no idea what "splinter" means.

Comment: I got the word "splinter" from the wikipedia page on iterated functions - although, reading it again, I'm pretty sure I parsed the sentence incorrectly.

Comment: I'd just call it a function of order two...

Comment: @JoséSiqueira And you would be pretty much alone in doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are **[involutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29)**. The orbits of an involution all have size $1$ or $2$.

What is a splinter?

Comment: I read "splinter" on the wikipedia article on iterated functions, but I don't think I even read the sentence correctly.

Comment: "Splinter" seems to go back to a suggestion by Ullian, J. in Splinters of Recursive Functions, The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 25, N. 1, March, 1960, pp. 33 - 38. I never met the term before and it does not seem to me to be much in use in any community (but I might be wrong).

Comment: I have some old lecture notes which call the splinter the sequence of functions you get from repeatedly applying the function, i.e., $\{f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), \ldots\}$, so I suppose a “splinter of size 2” might mean this sequence only has two distinct elements, or something similar.

Comment: I'd like to up vote, but that second sentence is blocking me. I've never seen the word orbit used to describe the set if powers of something. It's certainly not the standard use in group theory.

Comment: @alexwlchan Sequence of values, not sequence of functions.

Comment: @rschwieb Please stay blocked. Orbits in groups: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers

Comment: Dear @Did: Oh! I gather now you are thinking of the action of the map on its set, rather than some orbit of the involution in the group of transformations. I've got a tip: given the choice between a) explaining your thinking and b) returning a sarcastic remark with a link to basic algebra, choosing a) will be both more polite, faster, and more helpful to your peers (and students, if you have them.)  Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the tip. To summarize, you asserted something false that anybody can disprove in one minute using google and wikipedia, and when I provide the link, you lecture me on manners. Well... By the way, who was sarcastic first?